# ApiController HttpPost parameters

Tags: asp.net, post, model-view-controller

The httpPost transfer with parameters fails in the apiconroller.

It is trying to communicate from Android to Web server.
I succeeded in communicating with Get and Post, which had no parameters.
However, if parameter is added in Post transmission, it fails. I certainly think there is a problem with the Web server code.
The tutorial only contains information about the Model. I want to exchange strings.

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            //....
        }
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public class WebApiConfig
    {
        public const string UrlPrefix = "api";
        public const string UrlPrefixRelative = "~/" + UrlPrefix;

        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            var httpControllerRouteHandler = typeof(HttpControllerRouteHandler).GetField("_instance",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (httpControllerRouteHandler != null)
            {
                httpControllerRouteHandler.SetValue(null,
                    new Lazy<HttpControllerRouteHandler>(() => new SessionHttpControllerRouteHandler(), true));
            }

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: UrlPrefix + "/{controller}/{action}/{sn}",
                defaults: new { action = "Index", sn = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
        public class SessionControllerHandler : HttpControllerHandler, IRequiresSessionState
        {
            public SessionControllerHandler(RouteData routeData) : base(routeData) { }
        }
        public class SessionHttpControllerRouteHandler : HttpControllerRouteHandler
        {
            protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
                => new SessionControllerHandler(requestContext.RouteData);
        }
    }
```

ApiController.cs

```
public class LicenseController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetLicense([FromBody]string data)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetLicense2(string data)
        {
            string udid = data;
            string license = AES.Encrypt(udid);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, license);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetLicense3()
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "ABC");
        }


    }
```

android code

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try{
                        // Defined URL  where to send data
                            URL url = new URL("http://192.1.1.1:80/api/License/GetLicense/");

                            // Send POST data request

                            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                            conn.setDoOutput(true);
                            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                            //wr.write(URLEncoder.encode("data=3434", "UTF-8") );
                            wr.write("data=3434");
                            wr.flush();

                            // Get the server response

                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            String line = null;

                            // Read Server Response
                            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                            {
                                // Append server response in string
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }).start();
```

Comment: Try `wr.write("=3434");` instead `wr.write("data=3434");` just send the post data prepended with equal sign (=)

Comment: tried and succeeded ```wr.write ("=data=3434")```
And
```Public HttpResponseMessage GetLicense([FromBody]string data, string data2);``` What do I do?

wr.write ("=data=343434&data2=3232")"; fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a web api POST method accepting  a single string parameter you can do:

```
[HttpPost]
 public HttpResponseMessage GetLicense([FromBody]string data)
```

And then post the data from client like:
        `wr.write("=3434");`

For multiple post parameters, create a model class in Web API:

```
public class DataModel {
  public string data1 {get;set;}
  public string data2 {get;set;}
}
```

Update api endpoint parameter type:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GetLicense([FromBody]DataModel dataModel)
```

Then post json string from client with content-type: "application/json"

```
{
 "data1": "Data1 contents", 
 "data2":  "Data2 contents"
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to deliver it on Android?